# Click on Powerpoint Slide Pane

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

I'm working on a VB powerpoint tool. From Powerpoint Normal View when I select (click) a slide in the Left-hand Pane, if I don't click on the Slide Pane (the pane displaying a large view of the current slide), this Code line will not work.

```
Application.ActivePresentation.Windows(1).PointsToScreenPixelsY(0)
```

I got the following error message : "DocumentWindow(unknown member) : Illegal value."

Is there a way with VB to click on the Slide Pane?

Comment: No i'm using VB.net ... but if you have an idea I can adapt it in VB. Thanks

Comment: Hi everyone .... No answer??? Is there a Macro recorder in Powerpoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but just in case anyone else lands here like me for the same problem, here is how to solve it:

```
If ActiveWindow.ViewType = PpViewType.ppViewNormal AndAlso Then
  ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate()
End If
```

That is, you must activate the main slide pane (not the list of slides) before performing any actions, e.g. selection.